# Glidepoint usb trackpad suddenly not working

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, hardware-failure, touchpad

I have [this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16826152018) Adesso Glidepoint trackpad, which has worked flawlessly for a year. Then, about a week ago, over a couple days, it started acting flaky, then a blue screen of death, and now it doesn't work any more.

I've updated its driver, and disabled and reenabled it, restarted my computer a bunch, but it's just dead. It gives the USB bloopity bloop when its plugged in and out, but other than that, it's as if it's not there.

Is there anything left for me to try?

Thanks.

Comment: Try another computer. That should confirm that it is the device.

Comment: @Xavierjazz Thanks for the tip. I did, and it's dead  :(

Comment: You're welcome. I've added it as an answer and would appreciate it if you would accept it. Regards,

Comment: @Xavierjazz There's no answer yet. Just another comment  :)

Comment: The sysop converted my answer to a comment. "shrug".

Comment: @Xavierjazz So elaborate more. Make it more substantial than a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try another computer. If it works on that computer it is not the trackpad. If it does not work on that 2nd computer, that would confirm that the device is not working and I would replace it.